# Clipping raster file in ArcMap over the extent of polyline shape

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, clip, line, masking

I have a calculated raster file, overlayed on a shapefile with lines (like on figure)
[image: Raster and polyline shape]

I would like to clip the raster in ArcMap (since it is an interpolation and out of the vector shape it is mostly meaningless) to the extent, where the available data are on vector shape (on figure this is a clearly seen wedge or triangle, where the lines are present only). Of course, this can be done manually drawing appropriate polygon around the vector file. But the question is, whether it is possible to derive automatically a polygon mask from this vector layer for clipping the raster? The standard tools seem to suggest only clipping around a rectangular area, containing whole vector data.

Comment: Minimum bounding geometry http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000.htm should work. This creates a convex polygon enclosing all your contour lines then using Extract by Mask (SA) you should be able to extract the common part.

Comment: I believe that had you set the processing extent or mask in geoprocessing options to the contours layer when you originally created the raster, the output would have been constrained to where the contours are to start with, rather than having to clip it later. I'm pretty sure I've used that to limit things to non-rectangular bounds before.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003q000000) followed by [Clip (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009n000000) with the clipping geometry option or [Extract by Mask (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002n000000).

[image]

Comment: I could support that approach Aaron. It's what I would do.